# How prove this inequlity $\sum_{k=n}^{2n-3}\frac{|\sin{k}|}{k}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},n\ge 3$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

pove that:
$$\sum_{k=n}^{2n-3}\dfrac{|\sin{k}|}{k}<\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}},n\ge 3$$

This problem is my frend creat it today,Thank you someone can prove it.Thank you

my idea,long ago
I have prove it
$$\sum_{k=n}^{3n-1}\dfrac{|\sin{k}|}{k}>\dfrac{1}{6}$$
I use this
$$\min{\{|\sin{x}|,|\sin{(x+1)}|}\}>\dfrac{1}{3},x\in R$$

Comment: $\sum_{k=n}^{2n-3}\dfrac{|\sin{k}|}{k}<\sum_{k=n}^{2n-3}\dfrac{1}{k}<\ln\dfrac{2n-3}{n}=\ln(2-\dfrac3n)<\ln2,n\ge 3$ i get this upper bound and $\ln2$~=$0.69$ and $\dfrac1{\sqrt2}$~=$0.70$ the question is i am not sure the step is right..

Comment: @Xiaolong The denominator in the logarithm expression should be $n-1$. With a denominator of $n$, that logarithm in an integral over an interval that is $n-3$ units long, but the sum is over $n-2$ units.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you bound $|\sin(k)|$ by $1$, then

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=n}^{2n-3}\frac{|\sin k|}{k}& < \sum_{k=n}^{2n-3}\frac{1}{k}\\
&<\int_{n-1}^{2n-3}\frac{1}{x}\,dx\\
&=\ln\left(\frac{2n-3}{n-1}\right)\\
&=\ln\left(2-\frac{1}{n-1}\right)\\
&<\ln\left(2\right)\\
\end{align}
$$

And $\ln(2)<\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

---

Here is an improved bound. For $n\geq6$, at most one-half plus one of the values of $|\sin k|$ for $k$ in $\{k,k+1,\ldots,2k-6\}$ are greater than $1/\sqrt{2}$. These "large" values are spread out over $\{k,k+1,\ldots,2k-6\}$ but for the purposes of establishing an upper bound, we can put them all up front:

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=n}^{2n-6}\frac{|\sin k|}{k}& < \sum_{k=n}^{\lceil3n/2\rceil-2}\frac{1}{k}+\sum_{k=\lceil3n/2\rceil-1}^{2n-6}\frac{1}{k\sqrt{2}}\\
&<\int_{n-1}^{\lceil3n/2\rceil-2}\frac{1}{x}\,dx+\int_{\lceil3n/2\rceil-2}^{2n-6}\frac{1}{x\sqrt{2}}\,dx\\
&=\ln\left(\frac{\lceil3n/2\rceil-2}{n-1}\right)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\ln\left(\frac{2n-6}{\lceil3n/2\rceil-2}\right)\\
&\le\ln\left(3/2\right)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\ln\left(4/3\right)\approx0.6089\\
\end{align}
$$

You could tweak this to improve it. In the way that this cut in half, you could cut in thirds, etc. And if you want to make this more like the original question, you can bound the $2n-5$th, $2n-4$th, $2n-3$rd, and  $2n-2$nd, terms by $1/(2n-5)+1/(2n-4)+1/(2n-3)+1/(2n-2)$. And always look directly at the sum for small $n$.

Comment: Oh,Thank you,but I find $$\sum_{k=n}^{2n-2}\dfrac{|\sin{k}|}{k}<0.7\ln{2},n\ge 2$$,How prove it,Thank you alex,jordan

Comment: In fact this works even if you allow the sum to go up to $2n-2$. And then you can relax the $n\ge 3$ condition down to $n\ge 2$ to still have a nonempty sum.

Comment: That's a different question than the original one asked. If it's true, it makes use of the fact that $|\sin k|$ is, on average, closer to $2/\pi\approx0.6366$ than 1. And 0.7 gives a sizable enough wiggle room.

Comment: yes,so I don't prove it,can you help? Thank you

Comment: That's good job,I try it.Thank you,if I not,you can help me prove it? Thank you ,My english is poor.